# Why does Firefox recognize my XML data as XML but IE and Chrome see it as plaintext?

Tags: xml, perl, browser

My backend program generates some XML data and sends them to the client.
The backend response is like this:

```
print $cgi->header("Content-type: text/xml;charset=utf-8");
print "<?xml version='1.0' encoding = 'utf-8'?>";

< correct XML data goes here >
```

When I try to visualize the sent XML in Firefox, It gets the whole thing and everything is fine. But under Chrome and IE the XML header isn't received and XML data isn't displayed as it should (only like a plain text)!

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Do you _know_ the XML header isn't received, or do you assume it isn't since the XML doesn't display?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try refactoring your code

```
print header(-type=>'text/xml' , -charset=>'UTF-8');
```

See the [CGI.pm docs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI) on [CREATING A STANDARD HTTP HEADER](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI#CREATING_A_STANDARD_HTTP_HEADER:)

Comment: Thank you so much, now everything is working just fine! thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It might not like the spaces between encoding = 'utf-8' try encoding='utf-8'
I can't answer how chrome and IE parses xml but it could be as simple as that.